# Change href with window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm using jgfeed to retrive a feed with jquery. It works well.
It shows all the titles and the links.

This is the code:

```
        $.jGFeed('http://www.link.org/feed',
    function(feeds){
        if(!feeds){
            alert('No network');
        }
        for(var i=0;i<feeds.entries.length;i++){
            var entry = feeds.entries[i];
            var title = entry.title;
            var link = entry.link;              

            var html = "<ul class='pageitem'><li class='textbox'><span class='header'>" + title + "</span></li><li class='menu'><a href='" + link + "'><span class='name'>Read more</span><span class='arrow'></span></a></li></ul>";

            $("#feedContent").append($(html));
        }
    }, 20);
```

And in the html:

```
<div id="feedContent"></div>
```

But i need to do a window.open of every link instead the href. I tested a lot of things but I can't do it ...

Any help?

Comment: To be sure, you want to open a new window or do you want to open a new popup? And you want to make it so your `<a>` open up in a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you could setup your own event handler for links in the list.

```
$('.pageitem').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
   window.open( $(this).attr('href'), 'popup' );

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Note that we're using [`$.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) rather than `$.click()`.  This is because the `<a>` tags we're handling don't exist on page load. Using `delegate()` ensures that all future `<a>` tags in the list get the event handler.

Comment: Don't use `live()`! Even jQuery core members say not to use it. It's only still in there for legacy reasons. use `delegate()` instead. Much, much slower. http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live  && http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that about live().  I've updated accordingly.

Comment: Nice :) i think you are missing the first attribute tho. I believe you _have_ to give it a context to look for the new elements (one reason I think its faster than `live()`)

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention, the first attr should be like .delegate('#parentSelector','click',function(){...})

Comment: Have I got it right now?  I'm looking at the example on the delegate() api page and it seems like they have the parent first, then the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend keeping the href, just in case something goes wrong with the window open.

You can simply add a class to every link that you are appending in the html string, then after you append it, apply a click event to that class:

```
   $.jGFeed('http://www.link.org/feed',
function(feeds){
    if(!feeds){
        alert('No network');
    }
    for(var i=0;i<feeds.entries.length;i++){
        var entry = feeds.entries[i];
        var title = entry.title;
        var link = entry.link;              

        var html = "<ul class='pageitem'><li class='textbox'><span class='header'>" + title + "</span></li><li class='menu'><a href='" + link + "' class="external-link"><span class='name'>Read more</span><span class='arrow'></span></a></li></ul>";

        $("#feedContent").append($(html));
        $('.external-link').click(function() {
          window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'My_Window', 'width=800,height=600');
          return false;
        });
    }
}, 20);
```

Comment: I suggest this then: `var w=window.open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'), 'width=800,height=600'); return w?false:true;`
 - so I deleted my answer which did pass the href and target

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = "<ul class='pageitem'>" + 
           "  <li class='textbox'>" + 
           "   <span class='header'>" + title + "</span>" + 
           "  </li>" + 
           "  <li class='menu'>" + 

           "    <a href='" + link + "' target='new'>"; // <<-- Look here. Make 
          //this target unique if each link should open in its own page. use one 
          //target like "new" to open all links in one separate page.

    html +="      <span class='name'>Read more</span>" + 
           "      <span class='arrow'></span>" + 
           "    </a>" + 
           "  </li>" + 
           "</ul>";
```

Comment: it is _blank and not new. new will only open one new window, then reuse the window

Comment: not very clear. "new" sounded like you expected a new window each time